# WordPress plugin/code to to to next/previous post in same category

Tags: php

I have spent days looking for a WordPress plugin to automatically add next and previous links to the bottom of each post.  I have found loads of plugins but I want one that will restrict the posts shown to posts in the same category.

I really dont know anything about php to write a custom plugin myself so any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The Codex is your friend. There are core WordPress template tags for this. See @songdogtech's answer, below.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a plugin; see the docs for the parameters of next_post_link and previous_post_link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link